# How can a frame refresh/redraw be forced in Python GUI with tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

- When a user clicks on menubuttons , a function is called back.
- I want instead of calling functions , the frame area should be redrawn(like if a user clicks on NEW CUSTOMER, a booking form should be drawn , and if a user clicks on GUEST LIST then a table of guest list should be drawn.
- I want Menu bar to be displayed in every frame.

'

```
class NewMenu(Frame):

def __init__(self,parent=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    self.createWidget()
    self.master.title("Hotel Ganga Maiya-Hotel_ERP")
    self.master.iconname("tkpython")

def createWidget(self):
    self.makeMenuBar()
    self.makeToolBar()
    L = Label(self, text='Welcome Back')
    L.config(relief=SUNKEN, width=100, height=20, bg='white')
    L.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)

def makeToolBar(self):
    toolbar = Frame(self, cursor='hand2', relief=SUNKEN, bd=2)
    toolbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    Button(toolbar, text='Quit', command=self.quit) .pack(side=RIGHT)
    Button(toolbar, text='Engage Room', command=self.greeting) .pack(side=LEFT)

def makeMenuBar(self):
    self.menubar = Menu(self.master)
    self.master.config(menu= self.menubar)
    self.bookRoomMenu()
    self.viewDataMenu()
    self.accountingMenu()
    self.imageMenu()
    self.billingMenu()

def bookRoomMenu(self):
    pulldown= Menu(self.menubar)
    pulldown.add_command(label='New Customer', command=self.notdone)
    pulldown.add_command(label= 'Old Customer', command=self.quit)
    self.menubar.add_cascade(label='Book Room', underline=0, menu=pulldown)

def viewDataMenu(self):
    pulldown = Menu(self.menubar)
    pulldown.add_command(label= 'Room Number Wise', command=self.notdone)
    pulldown.add_command(label= 'Room Category Wise' , command=self.greeting)
   # pulldown.add_separator()
   # pulldown.add_command(label='Delete', command=self.greeting)
    #pulldown.entryconfig(4, state=DISABLED)
    self.menubar.add_cascade(label='Booking History', underline=0, menu=pulldown)

def accountingMenu(self):
    pulldown= Menu(self.menubar)
    pulldown.add_command(label='Account Calculater', command=self.notdone)
    pulldown.add_command(label= 'Some thing', command=self.notdone)
    self.menubar.add_cascade(label='Accounting', underline=0, menu=pulldown)

def imageMenu(self):
     self.menubar.add_cascade(label='Guest list', underline=0, )
   # photoFiles = ('nike.png','adidas.png','Avira.png')
   # pulldown = Menu(self.menubar)
    #self.photoObjs=[]
    #for file in photoFiles:
      #  img = PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/CyberSurvillence/Documents/img/' + file)
       # pulldown.add_command(image=img, command=self.notdone)
       # self.photoObjs.append(img)

    #self.menubar.add_cascade(label='Guest List', underline=0, menu=pulldown)


def billingMenu(self):
    #pulldown= Menu(self.menubar)
   # pulldown.add_command(label='Account Calculater', command=self.notdone)
   # pulldown.add_command(label= 'Some thing', command=self.notdone)
    self.menubar.add_cascade(label='Billing', underline=0, )

def greeting(self):
    showinfo('greeting','Greeting')

def notdone(self):
    showerror('Not implemented','Not yet available')

def quit(self):
    if askyesno('Verity quit','Are you sure you want to quit?'):
        Frame.quit(self)

if __name__ == '__main__': NewMenu().mainloop()
```

`

Comment: You should describe what kind of form you want when clicking menu button.

Comment: You've told us what you want, but you haven't actually asked a question. What part of the problem don't you understand?

Comment: Have the menubutton callback do the redrawing you want.  The Guestlist box could pop up a menu box or new Toplevel.

Comment: I want a from with entry fields and check-box .